# amount of times object was found

Tags: javascript

This code **alerts name of the object** every time it found one. How to make it **alert amount of times it found object**?

```
app.beginUndoGroup("Find  Keys"); // Start 
    var targetComp = app.project.activeItem; // Collect the active composition
    var selectedLayer = targetComp.selectedLayers; // Collect the selected layers

    for (e = 0; e <= selectedLayer.length-1; e++) { // Cycle through selected layers

        for (a = 1; a <= selectedLayer[e].transform.numProperties; a++) {; // Cycle through transform parameters
            var propToDelete = selectedLayer[e].transform.property(a); // Identify the parameter to find
            for (i = propToDelete.numKeys; i != 0; i--) { // Cycle through the Keyframes backwards
                alert(i); // Alert the current Keyframe
            }
        }
    }
    app.endUndoGroup(); // End
```

Comment: `e <= selectedLayer.length-1` ? Why not `e < selectedLayer.length` and change `alert(i);` to `someCounter++;` and have `var someCounter=0;` before the loop

Comment: Set up a variable and increment it?

Comment: mplungjan well.. it's the same result

Comment: @PavelVanchugov but very easy to break - especially when you later have `a = 1; a <= selectedLayer[e].transform.numProperties;`

Comment: thank you all, i starting to remember what is what now

Answer (score 1):

You want to define a variable outside of the first for loop and assign 0 to it
Then increment the variable instead of alerting i
Then after the for loop, alert the value of the declared variable

like so:
`var counter = 0` before `for (e =0; e...`

`counter++` instead of `alert(i)`

`alert(counter)` at the end

Answer (score 1):

Just add a variable `count = 0` at the start of the loop and add 1 each time it founds an object. At the end just `alert` the variable `count`.

```
    app.beginUndoGroup("Find  Keys"); // Start 
    var targetComp = app.project.activeItem; // Collect the active composition
    var selectedLayer = targetComp.selectedLayers; // Collect the selected layers
    var count = 0;
    for (e = 0; e <= selectedLayer.length-1; e++) { // Cycle through selected layers

        for (a = 1; a <= selectedLayer[e].transform.numProperties; a++) {; // Cycle through transform parameters
            var propToDelete = selectedLayer[e].transform.property(a); // Identify the parameter to find
            for (i = propToDelete.numKeys; i != 0; i--) { // Cycle through the Keyframes backwards
                alert(i); // Alert the current Keyframe
                count = count + 1; 
            }
        }
    }
    app.endUndoGroup(); // End
    alert(count);
```

Comment: thank you! i figured it out 1 seconds before)